# What comes after Cobalt and how do I get it?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast, minecraft-tinkers-construct

I have been playing around with Tinker's Construct lately and came across a mod called TAIGA, however WAILA calls it Tinkers' Alloying Addon. Anyways, I cannot figure out what ore I need to obtain to get past cobalt, seeming I cannot mine many of the ores that the mod adds. Can somebody please tell me what ore is next in the hardness tree and how do I get it?

**Note:** My Minecraft version is 1.10.2

Answer (score 2):

Try finding some [Ardite](http://tinkers-construct.wikia.com/wiki/Ardite) and combine it with Cobalt in the smeltery to get [Manyullyn](http://tinkers-construct.wikia.com/wiki/Manyullyn) which is the highest Ore that you can get in the normal Tinker's Construct. Though according to the curse page of the mod you should be able to mine some of the new ores already.

Check out the "What's going on?" section on [this](https://mods.curse.com/mc-mods/minecraft/247661-taiga-tinkers-alloying-addon) page to see which of the new ores have what mining level.

Comment: I seen that part,it just tells me the mining level and what it can mine, however it doesn't tell me how to get any of it

Comment: Ah, sorry, i can't help with that right now, though I'd recommend using NEI to check recpies for smelting (If any of them have to be made by smelting), and if it's an ore that is generated with the world it will tell you on which height it is most common (atleast from my experience it does). You just have to switch NEI to Recipe or Utility mode ( I don't remember which one it was, though I think it was Utility ) and then left click on the item in the NEI window.

Comment: @Jonco98 So you can't find where Ardite is in the world?

Comment: Nope, I have no clue where to find any of the new ores really

Comment: @Jonco98 , Silly question but, was the mod active when you generated the world? Also, Ardite is a rare ore that only spawns in the Nether, are you looking there? For the TAIGA Ores i sadly have no clue where they spawn

Comment: They spawn in all 3 dimensions but so for i havent found out how to mine any of them, even with a manyllullyn pickaxe i cant